# Python Web sacraping xlsx doesnt seems to work

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.directliquidation.com/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


links = soup.find_all('a')


excel_links = []
for link in links:
    if link['href'].endswith('.xlsx'):
        excel_links.append(link['href'])


for excel_link in excel_links:
    data = pd.read_excel(excel_link)
    print(data.head()) # print the first 5 rows of the Excel data
```

Getting al .xlsx from webpage

Comment: You're using `requests` to fetch the page content, which does not understand javascript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.